# How to manage user groups in Curity server, we are using oauth openid connect to curity. Need to create user groups and add users to the group

Tags: curity

We are using oauth openid connect to curity server with AEM cloud. Need to create user groups and add users to the group in curity and get the group in response when user logs in to system. On AEM side we need to retreive the group info from response and manage the user permissions.

We are new to curity, still exploring the options. If you could provide us any documentation around this.

Answer (score 1):

In OAuth/OpenID Connect you use tokens to transfer authorization/identity data. Consequently, you have to add a `groups` claim to the token that AEM processes.

## Add Custom Claim

Start with configuring a custom claim called `groups`. Navigate to the Token Designer in **Profiles** → **Token Service** → **Scopes**. Select the scope that should trigger the claim to be added to the token. Then click the `+ New` button in the claims column. Walk through the wizard and enter the details of the claim. Call the new claim `groups` and choose `Claims Provider` as the type of source of the value. Select a suitable claims provider and add the name of the attribute that hold the value (comparable to the database column, can but does not have to be the same as the claim name). Then specify any (optional) transformations and close the window. At the end, drag the claim to the token where it should end up. Commit the changes. Check out the tutorial [How to Implement Custom Claims](https://curity.io/resources/learn/implementing-custom-claims/) for a more detailed description.

If you want the `groups` to come from the account, you will need an account manager that fetches the attribute from a datasource and a claims provider that uses the account manager to retrieve the value for the claim. Make sure to deactivate the `Map the Account to OpenId Connect Claims` because this option would restrict the attributes to standard OpenId Connect Claims which does not include `groups`-

## Change User/Account Data

So, how to add groups to an account (user)? This is where User Management APIs play their role. The Curity Identity Server offers two APIs for user management. You can use either the GraphQL API or SCIM API to update users, e.g. to change their groups. The corresponding documentation can be found in [User Management with GraphQL](https://curity.io/resources/learn/graphql-user-management/) and [User Management with SCIM](https://curity.io/resources/learn/user-management/). `groups` are part of the default user-scheme in SCIM, so you should be able to use a standard SCIM client for your purpose.

## Role Based Access Control

There's even a tutorial that handles [Implementing Role Based Security](https://curity.io/resources/learn/implementing-role-based-security/) which I believe is solving an analogue problem to yours (using `roles` instead of `groups`).